# Run Geb test if element is displayed

Tags: testing, spock, geb

I would like to **run Geb Test conditionally, when some element is displayed**. Something like:

```
@IgnoreIf({element is not displayed})
    def "run element test"(){
       code for test here
    }
```

But *IgnoreIf* of *Requires* Spock expect just system and environment properties. Any idea?

Comment: Can you please explain a bit more about why you want to do this?

Comment: I have page, which is fully generated in CMS. In my page can be many components (cmp1, cmp2...n). My test should be able to test all possible components, but only when component is displayed on page. So test of particular component depends on whether it is displayed or not.